# Setting UI to be the same on different devices

Tags: android, user-interface, view

I am creating a game for android and I cant figure out how to keep the layout the same for different devices. I want it to look the same from my crummy little phone to a galaxy s. Here is what I am doing now. I tried to get the dimensions in the constructor, but it gave me errors for that, so i built my own mini constructor in the onDraw class.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
if (startup){//constructor part 2
        startup=false;
        height=canvas.getHeight();
        width=canvas.getWidth();
        xinc=width/(7/2);
        yinc=height/5;
        radius=width/6;
```

and so on. Is this the best way to do it? It seems to me that there should be another better way to do this. Also, do all android devices have same (I think its called the aspect ratio) width/height? Thanks in advance.

-Derek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android UI are normally written using xml and kept in the layout folder. The different resource folders can be given different name which will allow android to reference them according to different conditions.

This [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) is from the android documentation and it explains the different names the resoucrce folders can take.

Suppose you have an image that should have different size in different phones.
You can put the image with the same name in

drawable-ldpi/

drawable-mdpi/

drawable-hdpi/

So for an imageview when you use the command

```
imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
```

Android will check the density of the phone and take the icon image from the appropriate folder automatically. The same method can be done for layouts and the other subfolders of 'res'

From your question I see that you are overriding an 'onDraw' method of a view to do the UI. If thats the case, AFAIK you will have to measure the available space and create and measure your UI programatically.